# How to set an environment variable with PowerShell in Azure Devops release pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a function which will return a result. I am setting that result as an environment value in a pipeline. When I am invoking environment variable it's not printing the next two lines.

```
Write-Host "Before env : $result"
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=message]$result"
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

In other stage I invoked message other variable but it's not printing the next two lines.

```
write-host "After env :  $(message)"
[![enter code here][2]][2]
```

My only challenge was not getting the last two lines  which is ASDB_REPORT / ASDB_REPORT_TEST

Comment: Hi Bala, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: No , I can able to fetch the environment values in pipeline . But i can't able  to append  environment values more than 1 line

Answer (score 2):

If you set an environment variable with PowerShell in release pipeline, please refer to this doc: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-variables-in-scripts).

```
$result = 'crushed tomatoes'

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]$result"

# Write-Host "sauce: $(sauce)"
```

Please note that "Subsequent steps will also have the pipeline variable added to their environment. You cannot use the variable in the step that it is defined." Thus you could access to the new variable with [macro syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) and in tasks as environment variables.

```
Write-Host "sauce: $(sauce)"

Write-Host "my environment variable is $env:SAUCE"
```

However, you can't pass a variable from one job to another job or from one stage to another stage of release pipeline, unless you use [multi-stages YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Please refer to [Set a multi-job output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) for details.